# How to list all available form in delphi 7

Tags: delphi

i using delphi 7 and my project have many available form. 
i tried to execute `application.component[i].classname` to get all available form classname, but i only get list of created form classname.

is there way to get all available form classname in project to listbox?

Comment: What kind of program are you making where you can't keep track of which forms you made?

Comment: @david : complex, but i have to resolve it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the built in class registry.

- Register all your form classes by calling `RegisterClass(TMyForm)`. Do this from an initialization section, typically that of the unit which defines the class.
- When you want to recover the class from the registry, call `FindClass` passing the class name.
- For safety, check that `FindClass` returns a class that inherits from `TForm`.
- Finally create the form instance using either `Application.CreateForm` or just calling the `Create` virtual constructor of the class.

The instantiation looks like this:

```
var
  MyClass: TPersistentClass;
  Form: TForm;
....
MyClass := FindClass(ClassName);
if MyClass.InheritsFrom(TForm) then
  Form := TFormClass(MyClass).Create(AnOwner);
```

Comment: +1 I would check that the returned class inherits from TCustomForm, just in case...